# np.cov calculating covariance matrix: ValueError: m has more than 2 dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to compute the covariance matrix for three vectors. The vectors are converted into numpy arrays and then the covariance matrix is determined from this.

However I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment_1.py", line 263, in <module>
    main()
  File "assignment_1.py", line 33, in main
    s = pca(s)
  File "assignment_1.py", line 221, in pca
    covMatrix = np.cov(data,bias=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2367, in cov
    raise ValueError("m has more than 2 dimensions")
ValueError: m has more than 2 dimensions
```

The python program that I am using for this is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    s = pd.read_csv('A1-dm.csv')
    s = pca(s)

def pca(s):
    # Normalize each s
    A1 = s[['A1']].to_numpy()
    A2 = s[['A2']].to_numpy()
    
    print(A1.ndim)
    if 'A3' in s:
        A3 = s[['A3']].to_numpy()
        A3_norm = A3/np.linalg.norm(A3)

    A1_norm = A1/np.linalg.norm(A1)
    A2_norm = A2/np.linalg.norm(A2)

    data = np.array([A1_norm,A2_norm])
    if 'A3' in s:
        data = np.array([A1_norm,A2_norm,A3_norm])

    # determine covariance
    covMatrix = np.cov(data,bias=True)
    print(covMatrix)

    return s
    

main()
```

A sample of the dataset is

```
A1,A2,A3,Class
2,0.4631338,1.5,3
8,0.7460648,3.0,3
6,0.264391038,2.5,2
5,0.4406713,2.3,1
2,0.410438159,1.5,3
2,0.302901816,1.5,2
6,0.275869396,2.5,3
8,0.084782428,3.0,3
2,0.53226533,1.5,2
8,0.070034818,2.9,1
2,0.668631847,1.5,2
```

Why is the array size not 1D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` numpy matrix will have a shape `(3, 11, 1)` using the above example, i.e., a dimension of 3. [`np.cov`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) only accepts arrays of 1 or 2 dimensions thus it is returning an error.

To solve this, you can remove the axis of length 1 from `data` using [`np.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
if 'A3' in s:
  data = np.array([A1_norm,A2_norm,A3_norm]).squeeze()
```